# Copying a file during 'make install' results in 'The system cannot find the file specified'

Tags: qt, makefile, copy

I am trying to copy files during a `make install`, they are all copied but one is not pretending that the file does not exists :

```
copy /y C:\Qt\5.1.1\mingw48_32\bin\libstdc++-6.dll C:\Users\Aybe\Documents\GitHub\antimicro-aybe\antimicro\build-antimicro-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\release
The system cannot find the file specified.
Makefile.Debug:14739: recipe for target 'install_imageformats' failed
mingw32-make[1]: [install_imageformats] Error 1 (ignored)
```

- If I add double quotes around the filename and paste it in a command-line the copy works.
- If I use the 8dot3 notation (`libstd~1.dll`) the copy works, too.

Code used :

```
win32 {
    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
        DESTDIR = $$OUT_PWD/release
    } else {
        DESTDIR = $$OUT_PWD/debug
    }
    imageformats.path = $$DESTDIR
    imageformats.files += \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\icudt51.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\icuin51.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\icuuc51.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\libstdc++-6.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\libwinpthread-1.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\Qt5Core.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\Qt5Gui.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\Qt5Network.dll \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\Qt5Widgets.dll
    INSTALLS += imageformats
}
```

I've tried many things to escape `"` characters but none worked so far.

How can I successfully copy that file without having to use its 8dot3 name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is known as QT Bug 16372 : https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-16372

Using libstd~1.dll (DOS filename) as you said works for now as the bug is still unresolved as today (june 2014).